# Custom ALSA driver does not execute the open functions from struct snd_pcm_ops

Tags: linux, driver, alsa

I am trying to create my own custom sound driver using ALSA. So far I have succeeded loading the module, by which I mean:

- my probe function is executed
- the constructor is executed
- I see the interrupt being executed

I found this out by the dumps I placed in these functions.

But when I try to use the snd_pcm_open() function in my application, to connect to my driver, I do not see the dumps I added in the .open() function stored in struct snd_pcm_ops. So for some reason my driver is not seen from my application.

I loaded the original driver and executed the same application and it worked fine.

Do you have any idea why my driver is no accessible from user space?

Thank you.

And here is the code:

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>                         // MOD_DEVICE_TABLE,
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>                            // pci_device_id,
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/version.h>                        // KERNEL_VERSION,
#include <iso646.h>
#include <linux/kobject.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

#include <asm/io.h> 
#include <asm/uaccess.h>                          // copy_to_user,

#include <sound/core.h>
#include <sound/initval.h>
#include <sound/pcm.h>
#include <sound/pcm_params.h>

#include <linux/time.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
// vendor and device id of the PCI device
#define VENDOR_ID 0x8086
#define DEVICE_ID 0x2415

/*************** DATA **********************/
/* module parameters (see "Module Parameters") */
/* SNDRV_CARDS: maximum number of cards supported by this module */
static int index[SNDRV_CARDS] = SNDRV_DEFAULT_IDX;
static char *id[SNDRV_CARDS] = SNDRV_DEFAULT_STR;
static int enable[SNDRV_CARDS] = SNDRV_DEFAULT_ENABLE_PNP;

#define BARS 6
enum bars{bar0=0, bar1=1, bar2=2, bar3=3, bar4=4, bar5=5};

#define IOREG_0 0
#define IOREG_1 1

/*OFFSETS TO REGISTER*/
#define GLOBAL_STATUS_REGISTER_OFFSET 0x30

struct mem_regions
{
    unsigned int start_addr;
    unsigned int end_addr;
    unsigned int mem_len;
    unsigned int bar;
    unsigned int flag;

    void __iomem *mem_mapped_addr;
};

struct mychip {
    struct snd_card *card;
    struct pci_dev *pci;

    unsigned long port;
    int irq;

    struct mem_regions memregs[6];

    struct snd_pcm *pcm;
    struct snd_pcm_substream *substream;
};
/*******************************************/

/******************** FUNCTION PROTOTYPES *********************************/
static int __devinit snd_mychip_create(struct snd_card *card,
                       struct pci_dev *pci,
                       struct mychip **rchip);

static int snd_mychip_free(struct mychip *chip);                       

static irqreturn_t snd_mychip_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id);

static int __devinit snd_mychip_probe(struct pci_dev *pci,
                      const struct pci_device_id *pci_id);

static void snd_mychip_remove(struct pci_dev *pci);

static int snd_mychip_dev_free(struct snd_device *device);

static int reserve_mem_regions(struct mychip *chip);
static void clear_mem_regions(struct mychip *chip);

static void memdump(struct mychip *chip);

/* ------------ PCM functions ------------- */

/* ---- constructor ---- */
static int __devinit snd_pcm_constructor(struct mychip *chip);

/* ---- destructor ---- */
static void snd_pcm_destructor(struct snd_pcm *pcm);

/* ----  file operations fcns ---- */
static int snd_pcm_playback_open(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
static int snd_pcm_playback_close(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
static int snd_pcm_capture_open(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
static int snd_pcm_capture_close(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
/*snd_pcm_lib_ioctl();*/
static int snd_pcm_hw_params(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream,
             struct snd_pcm_hw_params *hw_params);
static int snd_pcm_hw_free(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
static int snd_pcm_prepare(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);
static int snd_pcm_trigger(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream, int cmd);
static snd_pcm_uframes_t snd_pcm_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream);

/* ---------------------------------------- */

/**************************************************************************/

/************************* IMPLEMENTATION *******************************/
/*prototyped*/
static int snd_mychip_free(struct mychip *chip)
{
    /* disable hardware here if any */
    //.... /* (not implemented in this document) */

    /* release the irq */
    if (chip->irq >= 0)
        free_irq(chip->irq, chip);

    /* release the I/O ports & memory */
    /*pci_release_regions(chip->pci);*/
    clear_mem_regions(chip);

    /* disable the PCI entry */
    pci_disable_device(chip->pci);

    /* release the data */
    kfree(chip);
    return 0;
}

/*prototyped*/
static int snd_mychip_dev_free(struct snd_device *device)
{
    return snd_mychip_free(device->device_data);
}

/*prototyped*/
static void snd_mychip_remove(struct pci_dev *pci)
{
  /*Clear the card data and PCI data*/
  snd_card_free(pci_get_drvdata(pci));
  pci_set_drvdata(pci, NULL);
}

/* constructor -- see "Constructor" sub-section *//*prototyped*/
static int __devinit snd_mychip_probe(struct pci_dev *pci,
                  const struct pci_device_id *pci_id)
{
    static int dev;
    struct snd_card *card;
    struct mychip *chip;
    int err;

    printk(KERN_ERR "Probing ...\n");

    /* (1) Check and increment the device index */
    if (dev >= SNDRV_CARDS)
        return -ENODEV;
    if (!enable[dev]) {
        dev++;
        return -ENOENT;
    }

    /* (2) Create a card instance */
    err = snd_card_create(index[dev], id[dev], THIS_MODULE, 0, &card);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    /* (3) Create a main component */
    /* chip-specific constructor: allocate PCI resources */
    err = snd_mychip_create(card, pci, &chip);
    if (err < 0) {
        snd_card_free(card);
        return err;
    }

    /* (4) Set driver ID and name strings */
    strcpy(card->driver, "My Chip");
    strcpy(card->shortname, "My Own Chip 123");
    sprintf(card->longname, "%s at 0x%lx irq %i",
        card->shortname, chip->port, chip->irq);

    /* (5) Create other components PCM, mixers, MIDI etc */
    /* implemented later */

    /* (6) Register card instance */
    err = snd_card_register(card);
    if (err < 0) {
        snd_card_free(card);
        return err;
    }

    /* (7) Set the PCI driver data */
    pci_set_drvdata(pci, card);
    dev++;

    /*Call PCM constructor*/
    err = snd_pcm_constructor(chip);
    if(err < 0)
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to execute PCM constructor!\n");

    printk(KERN_ERR "Probing done!\n");

    return 0;
}

/*prototyped*/
static irqreturn_t snd_mychip_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    struct mychip *chip = dev_id;
    struct timeval timeval;
    unsigned int status = 0;

    static int executed = 0;

    do_gettimeofday(&timeval);

    if(executed < 10)
    {

    /*get the global status register*/
    status = ioread32((void*)chip->memregs[IOREG_0].mem_mapped_addr + GLOBAL_STATUS_REGISTER_OFFSET);

    status = ioread32((void*)chip->memregs[IOREG_1].mem_mapped_addr + GLOBAL_STATUS_REGISTER_OFFSET);

    printk(KERN_ERR "\n---------- ISR -----------\n");

    executed ++;
    }

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

/* chip-specific constructor *//*prototyped*/
static int __devinit snd_mychip_create(struct snd_card *card,
                   struct pci_dev *pci,
                   struct mychip **rchip)
{
    struct mychip *chip;
    int err;
    static struct snd_device_ops ops = {
           .dev_free = snd_mychip_dev_free,
    };

    printk(KERN_ERR "Enabling PCI device ...");

    *rchip = NULL;

    /* initialize the PCI entry */
    err = pci_enable_device(pci);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;
    /* check PCI availability (28bit DMA) */
    if (pci_set_dma_mask(pci, DMA_BIT_MASK(28)) < 0 ||
        pci_set_consistent_dma_mask(pci, DMA_BIT_MASK(28)) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "error to set 28bit mask DMA\n");
        pci_disable_device(pci);
        return -ENXIO;
    }

    chip = kzalloc(sizeof(*chip), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (chip == NULL) {
        pci_disable_device(pci);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* initialize the stuff */
    chip->card = card;
    chip->pci = pci;
    chip->irq = -1;

    err = reserve_mem_regions(chip);
    if (err < 0) {
        kfree(chip);
        pci_disable_device(pci);
        return err;
    }

    /* (1) PCI resource allocation */
    if (request_irq(pci->irq, snd_mychip_interrupt,
            IRQF_SHARED, "My Chip", chip)) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "cannot grab irq %d\n", pci->irq);
        snd_mychip_free(chip);
        return -EBUSY;
    }
    chip->irq = pci->irq;

    printk(KERN_ERR "Gain access to PCI IRQ line ... line %d\n", pci->irq);
    printk(KERN_ERR "Gain access to PCI IO ports ... ports 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)chip->port);

    /* (2) initialization of the chip hardware */
    /*   (not implemented in this document) */

    err = snd_device_new(card, SNDRV_DEV_LOWLEVEL, chip, &ops);
    if (err < 0) {
        snd_mychip_free(chip);
        return err;
    }

    snd_card_set_dev(card, &pci->dev);

    *rchip = chip;
    return 0;
}    

static void memdump(struct mychip *chip)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<BARS; i++)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "\n-----------------------------------\n");
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].bar = %d\n", chip->memregs[i].bar);
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].start_addr = 0x%x\n", chip->memregs[i].start_addr);
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].end_addr = 0x%x\n", chip->memregs[i].end_addr);
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].mem_len = %d\n", chip->memregs[i].mem_len);
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].flag = 0x%x\n", chip->memregs[i].flag);
        printk(KERN_ERR "chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr = 0x%p\n", chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr);
}
}

static int reserve_mem_regions(struct mychip *chip)
{
    int res = 0;
    int i=0;

    res = pci_request_regions(chip->pci, "My Chip");
    if (res < 0) {
        return res;
    }

    for(i=0; i<BARS; i++)
    {
        chip->memregs[i].bar = i;
        chip->memregs[i].start_addr = pci_resource_start( chip->pci, i );
        chip->memregs[i].end_addr = pci_resource_end( chip->pci, i );
        chip->memregs[i].mem_len = pci_resource_len( chip->pci, i );
        chip->memregs[i].flag = pci_resource_flags( chip->pci, i );
        chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr = pci_iomap(chip->pci, i, 0);
    }

    memdump(chip);

    return res;
}


static void clear_mem_regions(struct mychip *chip)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<BARS; i++)
    {
        chip->memregs[i].bar = 0xFFFF;
        chip->memregs[i].start_addr = 0;
        chip->memregs[i].end_addr = 0;
        chip->memregs[i].mem_len = 0;
        chip->memregs[i].flag = 0xFFFF;

        pci_iounmap(chip->pci, chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr);
        chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr = NULL;
    }
    pci_release_regions(chip->pci);
}

/* ------------ PCM functions ------------- */    
static struct snd_pcm_hardware snd_hardware_setup =
{
    .info =         (SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP | SNDRV_PCM_INFO_INTERLEAVED |
                 SNDRV_PCM_INFO_BLOCK_TRANSFER |
                 SNDRV_PCM_INFO_MMAP_VALID |
                 SNDRV_PCM_INFO_PAUSE |
                 SNDRV_PCM_INFO_RESUME),
    .formats =      SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S16_LE,
    .rates =        SNDRV_PCM_RATE_8000_48000,
    .rate_min =     8000,
    .rate_max =     48000,
    .channels_min =     2,
    .channels_max =     2,
    .buffer_bytes_max = 128 * 1024,
    .period_bytes_min = 32,
    .period_bytes_max = 128 * 1024,
    .periods_min =      1,
    .periods_max =      1024,
    .fifo_size =        0,
};

/* ---- operator structs ---- */
static struct snd_pcm_ops snd_pcm_playback_ops = {
    .open =     snd_pcm_playback_open,
    .close =    snd_pcm_playback_close,
    .ioctl =    snd_pcm_lib_ioctl,
    .hw_params =    snd_pcm_hw_params,
    .hw_free =  snd_pcm_hw_free,
    .prepare =  snd_pcm_prepare,
    .trigger =  snd_pcm_trigger,
    .pointer =  snd_pcm_pointer,
};

static struct snd_pcm_ops snd_pcm_capture_ops = {
    .open =     snd_pcm_capture_open,
    .close =    snd_pcm_capture_close,
    .ioctl =    snd_pcm_lib_ioctl,
    .hw_params =    snd_pcm_hw_params,
    .hw_free =  snd_pcm_hw_free,
    .prepare =  snd_pcm_prepare,
    .trigger =  snd_pcm_trigger,
    .pointer =  snd_pcm_pointer,
};

/* ----  file operations fcns ---- */
static int snd_pcm_capture_open(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct mychip *chip = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    int err = -10;

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> snd_pcm_capture_open()\n");

    runtime->hw = snd_hardware_setup;
    chip->substream = substream;

    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_capture_close(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    int err = -10;

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> snd_pcm_capture_close()\n");

    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_playback_open(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    struct mychip *chip = snd_pcm_substream_chip(substream);
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    int err = -10;

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> snd_pcm_playback_open()\n");

    runtime->hw = snd_hardware_setup;
    chip->substream = substream;

    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_playback_close(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    int err = -10;

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> snd_pcm_playback_close()\n");

    return err;
};

/*snd_pcm_lib_ioctl();*/
static int snd_pcm_hw_params(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream,
             struct snd_pcm_hw_params *hw_params)
{
    int err = 0;
    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_hw_free(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    int err = 0;
    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_prepare(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    int err = 0;
    return err;
};

static int snd_pcm_trigger(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream, int cmd)
{
    int err = 0;
    return err;
};

static snd_pcm_uframes_t snd_pcm_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)
{
    int err = 0;
    return err;
};

/* ---- constructor ---- */
static int __devinit snd_pcm_constructor(struct mychip *chip)
{
    struct snd_pcm *pcm = NULL;
    int err = 0;

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: running...\n");

    err = snd_pcm_new(chip->card, "My Own Chip", 0, 1, 1, &pcm);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR ">>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: Failed to execute snd_pcm_new()!\n");
        return err;
    }
    pcm->private_data = chip;
    pcm->private_free = snd_pcm_destructor;

    strcpy(pcm->name, "My Own Chip");
    chip->pcm = pcm;

    /*set operators*/
    snd_pcm_set_ops(pcm, SNDRV_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, &snd_pcm_playback_ops);
    snd_pcm_set_ops(pcm, SNDRV_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, &snd_pcm_capture_ops);

    /*stream preallocation of buffers*/
    err = snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all(pcm, SNDRV_DMA_TYPE_DEV, snd_dma_pci_data(chip->pci), 64*1024, 64*1024);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR ">>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: Failed to execute snd_pcm_lib_preallocate_pages_for_all()!\n");
    return err;
    }

    printk(KERN_ERR ">>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: ... exiting.\n");

    return 0;   
}

/* ---- destructor ---- */
static void snd_pcm_destructor(struct snd_pcm *pcm)
{
    /*
    struct mychip *chip = snd_pcm_chip(pcm);
    */
}

/* ---------------------------------------- */
/* PCI IDs */
static struct pci_device_id snd_mychip_ids[] = {
    { VENDOR_ID, DEVICE_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, snd_mychip_ids);

/* pci_driver definition */
static struct pci_driver driver = {
    .name = "My Own Chip",
    .id_table = snd_mychip_ids,
    .probe = snd_mychip_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(snd_mychip_remove),
};

/**************** MODULE EXCUTED FUNCTIONS ****************************/
/* module initialization */
static int __init alsa_card_mychip_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "\n\n\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n");
    printk(KERN_ERR "-->>> Module init: !!!");
    return pci_register_driver(&driver);
}

/* module clean up */
static void __exit alsa_card_mychip_exit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver(&driver);
    printk(KERN_ERR "-->>> Module exit: ");
}
module_init(alsa_card_mychip_init)
module_exit(alsa_card_mychip_exit)
```

And the output I get from dmesg:

```
[  227.202006] @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[  227.202430] -->>> Module init: !!!
[  227.202507] Probing ...
[  227.203959] Enabling PCI device ...
[  227.207882] 
[  227.207882] -----------------------------------
[  227.208097] chip->memregs[i].bar = 0
[  227.208124] chip->memregs[i].start_addr = 0xd100
[  227.208148] chip->memregs[i].end_addr = 0xd1ff
[  227.208174] chip->memregs[i].mem_len = 256
[  227.208198] chip->memregs[i].flag = 0x40101
[  227.208223] chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr = 0x0001d100
[  227.208246] 
[  227.208246] -----------------------------------
[  227.208271] chip->memregs[i].bar = 1
[  227.208294] chip->memregs[i].start_addr = 0xd200
[  227.208318] chip->memregs[i].end_addr = 0xd23f
[  227.208341] chip->memregs[i].mem_len = 64
[  227.208364] chip->memregs[i].flag = 0x40101
[  227.208388] chip->memregs[i].mem_mapped_addr = 0x0001d200
[  227.208410] 
[  227.208410] -----------------------------------
[  227.208435] chip->memregs[i].bar = 2
.....
[  227.209080] Gain access to PCI IRQ line ... line 5
[  227.209104] Gain access to PCI IO ports ... ports 0x0
[  227.224202] >>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: running...
[  227.225378] >>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: ... exiting.
[  227.225403] Probing done!
[  227.295404] 
[  227.295404] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.313297] 
[  227.313297] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.327248] 
[  227.327248] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.344968] 
[  227.344968] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.351703] 
[  227.351703] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.360189] 
[  227.360189] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.371751] 
[  227.371751] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.387809] 
[  227.387809] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.396767] 
[  227.396767] ---------- ISR -----------
[  227.413297] 
[  227.413297] ---------- ISR -----------
```

You see here the

- probe function being called(Probing ...)
- enabling the PCI device(Enabling PCI device ...)
- the memory regions being allocated
- the interrupt line (line 5)
- the PCM constructors (>>> PCM CONSTRUCTOR: running...)
- some dumps from the interrupt handler.

And some lines from my application:

```
/* Open PCM device for playback. */
rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
if (rc < 0) {
 printf(
         "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
         snd_strerror(rc));
  exit(1);
}
printf("Device opened ... rc = %d \n", rc);
```

Here I try to open my device. If you pay attention to the driver code above the playback_open() function should printk() some message and should return -10. I did this intentionally. But my application shows that the result from snd_pcm_open() is OK(zero I mean). So it looks like my application does not see my driver but tries to use something else.

I will place also all sound the modules being loaded currently:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
...
alsa                   13273  0 //this is my driver
snd_ac97_codec        105592  0 
snd_pcm                80357  2 alsa,snd_ac97_codec
snd_page_alloc         14036  1 snd_pcm
ac97_bus               12670  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51256  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              24503  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    62027  7 alsa,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,
snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              14599  1 snd
```

Here is the output from lspci -v which will show the info for the audio device:

```
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
I/O ports at d100 [size=256]
I/O ports at d200 [size=64]
Kernel driver in use: My Own Chip
Kernel modules: snd-nedelinxalsaxpci, snd-intel8x0
```

I build my kernel with my driver, because I thought this might help, but it did not(snd-nedelinxalsaxpci is my driver, and snd-intel8x0 is the original module). "My Own Chip" comes from my driver.

I don't know what other info I could give you. 
And thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: I'd guess the PCM device is not registered correctly, or your code does not open the correct PCM device. But it's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi, I will place now the code. I know it is really messy and probably does not make sense on places, but this is just an experiment.

Comment: I see no obvious reason. Is the device listed with `aplay -l`?

Comment: No it is not listed: this is what I get after aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

Comment: Could you be convinced to show which `printk`s actually get executed?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the the code will be enough. I will place above the output I get. I get all printk's execpt those I placed in snd_pcm_capture/playback_open() and the rest of the function wich are accessible from user space.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling the PCM constructor *after* the call to `snd_card_register`.
Sound card devices are accessible to userspace only if they are registered after they are created.

There is even a comment in your code that tells you about the correct place to do this:

```c
/* (5) Create other components PCM, mixers, MIDI etc */
```